# convert UploadFile object to a ZipFile object

Tags: jsp

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <%
       // decode source request:
 try {
      MultipartFormDataRequest multiPartRequest = new MultipartFormDataRequest(request);

    // get the files uploaded:
      Hashtable files = multiPartRequest.getFiles();

       ZipFile userFile = (ZipFile)files.get("bootstrap_file");

       if (! files.isEmpty()) {

       BootstrapDataManager bdm = new BootstrapDataManager(userFile);

       bdm.bootstrapStudent();
       bdm.bootstrapCourse();
       bdm.bootstrapSection();
       bdm.bootstrapBid();
       bdm.bootstrapCompletedCourses();
       bdm.bootstrapPreRequisite();
  }
       } catch (Exception error) {

    // set error flag in session:
    request.getSession().setAttribute("error", error);

    // throw its further to print in error-page:
    throw error;
  }


%>
    </body>
</html>
```

the BidDataManager takes in a ZipFile object in its constructor and i want to know how to convert an UploadFile object to a ZipFile object in order to pass it as a parameter..

Comment: Please add the appropriate language / platform tags. Thank you!

Comment: And if you're including a code example make it correctly formatted and make sure at least that the brackets match up.

Comment: i have added in the necessary info.. do you know what i can do?

Answer (score 0):

There must be a method which returns an `InputStream` so that you can write it to `FileOutputStream` yourself like `uploadFile.getInputStream()`, or a method which takes a `File` like `uploadFile.write(file)`.

Either way, you need to end up with a `File` so that you can pass it to the constructor of `ZipFile`. You can if necessary make use of [`File#createTempFile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to make it a TEMP file so that you don't need to worry about cleanup.

Regardless, a JSP is the wrong place for this job. I recommend to learn servlets before it's too late.